# How to code for loop for an element that consists of two component?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I would like to use for loop for the following calculation.
Since several elements of A have two components, for example: A[4] = [1,3], could anyone let me know how to code so that I could get the results as stated in the #Expected result, please?

```
n = 4
w = 5
m = np.array([2,1,3,1])
z = np.array([1,0,2,0])
c = np.array([50,20,100,30])
A = np.array([1,2,3,4,[1,3],[1,4],[2,4]]) #index for z and c

# Expected result

The formula is R = 1/(1+Σz)*Σ(2*w + c)

for i in range(len(A)):
  R = 1/(1+z[0])*(2*w + c[0])
  R = 1/(1+z[1])*(2*w + c[1])
  R = 1/(1+z[2])*(2*w + c[2])
  R = 1/(1+z[3])*(2*w + c[3])
  R = 1/(1+**z[0] + z[2]**)*{**(2*w + c[0]) + (2*w + c[2]**)} 
  R = 1/(1+z[0] + z[3])*{(2*w + c[0]) + (2*w + c[3])}
  R = 1/(1+z[1] + z[3])*{(2*w + c[1]) + (2*w + c[3])}
```

Comment: Are the first 4 elements of `A` single integers?

Comment: Yes, it is. So, for A: first four elements are single integer, the rest 3 elements are two integers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
R = np.zeros(A.size)
for k, idx in enumerate(A):
    # get z and c
    z_lst = z[np.array(idx)-1]
    c_lst = c[np.array(idx)-1]

    # compute R
    R[k] = 1/(1+np.sum(z_lst))*np.sum(2*w+c_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

for a in S:
Σz = 0
Σwvc = 0
for i in a:
#find sum z
zi = z[i]
Σz += zi

```
#find sum wvc
wvc = 2*w + v + c[i]
Σwvc += wvc
```

R4 = (1/(1+Σz))*(((n+1-2*len(a))*(2*v + 2*w)+Σwvc))